# what book is similar to john carter, but hero possessed a green alien's body on low gravity planet

Tags: story-identification, teleportation, gravity

please help me find the name of this book.  I read a book when I was young, the human hero's consciousness gets transported to the mind of an alien being on a distant low-G planet.  The alien being is a member of a thin, physically weak, green race (as i can remember).  This Green race is dominated by a race of large, hairy,  tusked beings.  Given that the human hero is a soldier he takes over the body of the green alien in a attempt to fight the hairy beings.  Somehow toward the end of the book the human's body is transported and reunited with his mind.  Given the alien planet's low-G the human is much stronger in his newly reacquired body than the hairy aliens, despite a significant size difference.  There is some kind of fight in a gladiatorial arena,(if my memory serves me right).

thanks

Comment: roughly how long ago were you "young"? do you have any memories of the book's cover?

Comment: approx 20 years ago. but the story seemed older than that,  maybe written 30 years ago. I believe the cover had the hairy tusked alien engaged in a fight with the human

Comment: Just to be 100% certain, you're not misremembering the early cover art which shows a human John Carter squaring off against a giant hairy tusked green being?

http://www.standbyformindcontrol.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Book-1-A-Princess-Of-Mars-1.jpg

Comment: I dont believe so, but I was only 12 or 13 so I might be "remembering" an image from my imagination.

Comment: no.  that is certainly no the the image i remember.  the hairy alien may have had "claws" similar to Wolverine for X-men.

Comment: deffinety not "john carter".  the human hero was a futuristic military astronaut.